# Font quality is not good when printing sales bill in webpage using TVS dotmatrix printer

Tags: php, fonts, printers, dot-matrix

I have created sales bill page in PHP. The preview of sales bill page is good. I have used "window.print()" to print the page. But if I print that content in TVS Dot-matrix printer, the font not clear and low quality. Are there any solutions?

Comment: Not entirely sure if you're serious: if you're using a dot-matrix printer, the first and very obvious answer is "get a modern printer"?

Comment: For sales bill, customers used dot matrix only. It is less of cost

Comment: Sure, but a dot matrix printer is an extremely low DPI device, whereas modern fonts are high DPI vector instructions, so without very specific additional details it is almost guaranteed the problem here is you're using a dot matrix printer, not a programming programing related to the font technology itself.